# Cant deploy Passenger with Nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, passenger

I have been following [this tutorial](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/deploy/ruby/digital_ocean/nginx/oss/trusty/deploy_app.html) to deploy Phusion Passenger with Nginx, and after finishing, I still get an error when I open the URL with the IP address (http://123.123.123.123)

When I watch the error.log from nginx, I see this:

http://pastie.org/pastes/10358955/text?key=s16vrhu2cofrian1hluwa

From that log, i noticed this:

> Warning: compilation didn't succeed. To learn why, read this file: App 15789 stderr:      /tmp/passenger_native_support-1g8vwu3.log

So this is the output of that file:

http://pastie.org/pastes/10358951/text

What is the problem here? Why is my rails app not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install a javascript runtime.  Simplest solution is to add therubyracer to your Gemfile.

```
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
```

It also seems you need to install either curl or wget based on the log.

Answer (score 6):

Actually, the problem is not so much the lack of a Javascript runtime. While the error message does mention "Could not find a JavaScript runtime", the *actual* problem is that your PATH environment variable isn't set correctly.

The indicator is in these two seemingly unimportant error messages:

```
App 15789 stderr: sh: 1: 
App 15789 stderr: env: not found
```

`env` is a common Unix command, located in /usr/bin. Node.js, as well as pretty much everything else, is also located in /usr/bin. If the system cannot find `env` then that means your PATH environment variable isn't set correctly.

The reason why it isn't set correctly, is most likely because Nginx [nuked your environment variables](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#env). Try adding this to your Nginx config file:

```
# Don't nuke PATH; preserve original value.
env PATH;
```

Comment: You are awesome. I was also facing same issue and wasn't sure whether it was passenger issue or nginx. I tried everything to set $PATH variable in passenger. Thank you so much for such a good explanation. 

Can you please also tell me why has nginx started nuking the PATH variable whereas initially it didn't use to?

Comment: env PATH;

added to nginx.conf fixed it for me. Thanks!